# Using the file name to determine if a SSIS package should be executed

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I've got 4 different companies whose spreadsheets I have to process.  Currently, if I receive a set of files, the SSIS solution is set to execute all of the packages in the solution whether I received the files or not.  I want to change this behavior by looking the the Source directory that stores the .xlsx files.

For instance, I have the files from two companies: A & B.  The file names will always be in this format with the companies' name at the beginning of the file name.

[image]

From there, I would like to use the file names to possibly set variables (? - not sure if this would be the best way ) to set precedence constraints to only execute the packages that relate to the companies' files we received.

Based on the screen shots, I want the packages of Company A & B to execute while C & D are skipped and then to move on to the next package.

Suggestions on how to achieve this goal?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your Task Flow Connections to be conditional instead. Also, why do you have a Foreach Loop Container with nothing inside it?

Comment: Mainly because this is how I envision it being set up but I'm not sure how to do it. I've been looking at other posts on SO and this how other similar tasks have been handled - but I know it's not complete and needs more but I don't know how at this point.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a boolean variable for each company.

```
@CompanyA_Recd, @CompanyB_Recd, @CompanyC_Recd, @CompanyD_Recd
```

Your foreach loop would loop through the files, analyze each file name, and mark the appropriate variable as true if you received that company's files.

Then your precedence constraints could just check the variable for that company.

Note that, depending on the logic you want for executing the `Final Report Package`, this means you might need two precedence constraints for each company.   One that goes to the package if the variable is true, and one that goes straight to the final package if the variable is false.

Comment: What are you saying makes sense - going to see if I can implement this logic.